# Can I use Ampl magic inside python code and not in ipython?

Tags: python, ampl

I am creating a simulation in python. In this simulation I need to solve optimization problem with ampl (lots of them). Is it possible to call ampl from python. I found iampl, but it only runs on ipython.

What I am doing right now: Writing a temporary data file, and solving it using on command line using os.system(). AMPL writes a solution file and then python reads it.

In this case I need to reset and create the model again and solve it from scratch. Is it possible to modify the current model and resolve it. I am guessing that will be faster.

Any guidance in this matter will be very helpful.